# Nissan X-Trail T31 A/T error when put it in manual mode

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, x-trail, sequential-transmission

I have a Nissan X-Trail 2010 T31 with 138.000kms automatic, and when i put the gear stick in manual mode (sequential mode), nothing happens! I can't change gears manually. It seems to be disabled.

[image]

In my central lcd monitor this icons do not appear:
[image]

I have all time only this icon:
[image]

Any ideas? Have some disabled mode this functionality?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the check engine light come up at all?

Comment: Yes, all dashboard lights works fine. But in the central monitor, the PRND icons do not appear. Only I have a fixed icon of manual transimision!

Comment: I had same problem with my 2011 T31 2.0 Dci. I don't know what caused it, but problem was fixed when battery accidently went empty and dash board trip computer reseted because of that. Now been working couple weeks normally. Did you find any solution in your case?

Comment: In my case, the gearbox control unit has a problem, luckily it was under warranty and they fixed it without paying